# Any way to set xerrors.Caller(1) when output an error by xerrors.Errorf()?

Tags: go

Running the below code, the stack trace is outputted with the line number of `fmt.Print(...)`. But I want to output the line of `logError(err)`. I think I need to call `xerrors.Caller(1)` to do that but I don't know how. Help me.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "golang.org/x/xerrors"
)

func main() {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile("")
    if err != nil {
        logError(err)
        return
    }
}

func logError(err error) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", xerrors.Errorf(": %w", err))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "golang.org/x/xerrors"
)

func doWhatever() error {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile("")
    if err != nil {
        return xerrors.Errorf("failed doing whatever: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := doWhatever()
    if err != nil {
        logError(err)
        return
    }
}

func logError(err error) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
}
```

Comment: I hadn't solved this problem but now I can rewrite my error handling code in the nice way you gave. Thanks!

Comment: I was researching about stack trances and stumbled on your question. It made me notice that with the `xerrors` package it's possible by using the `Errorf` function. Thank you too!